# После вставки иконки или же картинки в div, сам ряд div'ов разъезжается

Tags: html, css

[image: Разъехались div'ы]

Код HTML:

```css
.description {
  width: 100%;
  height: 592px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.desc_block1 {
  width: 465px;
  height: 160px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  /* margin: 15px 0px -20px 470px;*/
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.desc_block2 {
  width: 465px;
  height: 160px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  /* margin: 0px 0px 0px 470px;*/
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.desc_block3 {
  width: 480px;
  height: 160px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  /* margin: 0px 0px 25px 30px;*/
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.desc_block4 {
  width: 480px;
  height: 160px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  /* margin: 0px 0px 0px 30px;*/
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="description">
  <span class="title_of_description">КРОВЛЯ <span class="red_word">ПРОФИ</span> – это:</span>
  <div class="desc_block1"><img src="img/icon_of_description1.png" class="icon_of_descr1"><img src="img/line.png" class="line"><span class="title_of_fdesc">Экологичность и безопасность</span><br><span class="first_block_desc">Наличие сертификатов качества на весь используемый строительный материал дает Вам уверенность в его экологичности и безопасности. </span></div>
  <div class="desc_block3"><img src="img/icon_of_description3.png" class="icon_of_descr3"><img src="img/line.png" class="line"><span class="title_of_thirddesc">Качество работ</span><br><span class="third_block_desc">Все строители сертифицированы, осуществляется тех. надзор. Отлаженный процесс доставки и монтажа позволяет нам максимально сократить срок сдачи объекта. </span></div>
  <div class="desc_block2"><img src="img/icon_of_description2.png" class="icon_of_descr2"><img src="img/line.png" class="line"><span class="title_of_secdesc">Контроль расходов</span><br><span class="sec_block_desc">Наличие сертификатов качества на весь используемый строительный материал дает Вам уверенность в его экологичности и безопасности.</span></div>
  <div class="desc_block4"><img src="img/icon_of_description4.png" class="icon_of_descr4"><img src="img/line.png" class="line"><span class="title_of_fourthdesc">Гарантийные обязательства</span><br><span class="fourth_block_desc">Мы даём гарантию на все наши кровельные материалы и работы до 50 лет, прописывая соответствующие пункты в договоре.</span></div>
</div>
```

Помогите пожалуйста)

Comment: напишите нормальный html код и css

Comment: попробуйте воспользоваться `vertical-align:top`.

Comment: Лучше всего height прописать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это для примера

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.items {
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
}

.item h2 {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.item p,
.fa {
  font-size: .9em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="items">
  <div class="item">
    <h2><i class="fa fa-briefcase" aria-hidden="true"></i>Энергичность и безопасность</h2>
    <p>Гарантийные обязательства Мы даём гарантию на все наши кровельные материалы и работы до 50 лет, прописывая соответствующие пункты в договоре.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h2><i class="fa fa-bug" aria-hidden="true"></i>Качество работ</h2>
    <p>Экологичность и безопасность Наличие сертификатов качества на весь используемый строительный материал дает Вам уверенность в его экологичности и безопасности.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h2><i class="fa fa-diamond" aria-hidden="true"></i>Кантроль расходов</h2>
    <p>Качество работ Все строители сертифицированы, осуществляется тех. надзор. Отлаженный процесс доставки и монтажа позволяет нам максимально сократить срок сдачи объекта. </p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h2><i class="fa fa-bell" aria-hidden="true"></i>Гарантийные обязательства</h2>
    <p>Контроль расходов Наличие сертификатов качества на весь используемый строительный материал дает Вам уверенность в его экологичности и безопасности</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Может пробел добавить между иконкой и заголовком

Answer (score 1):

Flex - Рекомендую...

```css
.description {
  width: 100%;
  height: 592px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.down {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

img {
  margin-left: 5px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.desc_block {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.desc {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="description">
  <div class="up">
    <span>КРОВЛЯ ПРОФИ – это:</span>
  </div>
  <div class="down">
    <div class="desc_block">
      <div class="iconBlock">
        <img src="http://the-x.clan.su/forum1.gif" class="icon_of_descr1" />
        <img src="http://the-x.clan.su/forum1.gif" class="line" />
        <span>Экологичность и безопасность</span>
      </div>
      <div class="desc">
        <span>Наличие сертификатов качества на весь используемый строительный материал дает Вам уверенность в его экологичности и безопасности. </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="desc_block">
      <div class="iconBlock">
        <img src="http://the-x.clan.su/forum1.gif" class="icon_of_descr1" />
        <img src="http://the-x.clan.su/forum1.gif" class="line" />
        <span>Экологичность и безопасность</span>
      </div>
      <div class="desc">
        <span>Наличие сертификатов качества на весь используемый строительный материал дает Вам уверенность в его экологичности и безопасности. </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="desc_block">
      <div class="iconBlock">
        <img src="http://the-x.clan.su/forum1.gif" class="icon_of_descr1" />
        <img src="http://the-x.clan.su/forum1.gif" class="line" />
        <span>Экологичность и безопасность</span>
      </div>
      <div class="desc">
        <span>Наличие сертификатов качества на весь используемый строительный материал дает Вам уверенность в его экологичности и безопасности. </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="desc_block">
      <div class="iconBlock">
        <img src="http://the-x.clan.su/forum1.gif" class="icon_of_descr1" />
        <img src="http://the-x.clan.su/forum1.gif" class="line" />
        <span>Экологичность и безопасность</span>
      </div>
      <div class="desc">
        <span>Наличие сертификатов качества на весь используемый строительный материал дает Вам уверенность в его экологичности и безопасности. </span>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```